# error including eps in my document

Tags: graphics, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t pdflatex print EPS figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures)

I'm trying to add eps graphic to my document but I got this error when I compile it

```
 Package pdftex.def Error: File `immagini/pwr_consumption_in_wnc-eps-converted
-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

where pwr_consumption_in_wnc is my eps file

Comment: A bit more information about your system and file might be helpful

Comment: Can you try with a filename that uses only letters but no dashes/underscores, preferably something short?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/19384 for more on this issue

Comment: This looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures: dupe?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge pdftex doesn't support .eps by default. But you could try the following:

1. `\usepackage{epstopdf}`
2. `\includegraphics{<name>}`
3. `pdflatex --shell-escape`

This should then produce a pdf version of your eps, which will then be used.

If your not depending on `pdflatex` you could go the other way: `latex->dvi->ps->pdf`