# LaTex => ps => pdf

Tags: compiling

I have just installed TeXnicCenter on my new computer and I am trying to use `LaTex => ps => pdf` profile as I was using this with my old computer.  I checked all profile settings from `output profile` and they match settings of my old computer.  However for some reason, the `.pdf` file is not being created.  The only files created are `.aux`, `.bbl`, Performance monitor file, `.dvi`, Text, and `.dwg` TrueView PostScript support file.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You might have a look at [this](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/help/faqs/latex/conversions) for the correct compilation sequence. From what you say it seems the step between `dvi` and `ps` is missing/broken.
If all you want is a `pdf` output and you have no other reasons to go via `dvi`, consider `pdflatex` as a single step, rather than the long sequence you're using.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have figures in .eps format.  can i use pdflatex in this case?

Comment: yes. see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/eps-figures-with-pdflatex) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures/387#387).

Comment: thanks, i did as suggested but instead of the figures i am getting an empty box with the link to my .eps file.  in fact i've got some errors while compiling

Comment: i think the problem is with the write18 or shell escape.  i don't know how to enable these can you advise please?

Comment: shell escape is easily activated by adding `-shell-escape` when invoking `pdflatex`. i.e. in TeXnicCenter where the commands for the compilation options are defined in the settings, add `-shell-escape` before the filename

Comment: sorry but i'm not an expert with latex.  so in teXnicCenter i go to build-output profiles right? and then where shall i add the -shell-escape?

Comment: within those settings, what's the setting for `pdflatex` - I don't have TeXnicCenter here atm.

Comment: LaTeX setting: command line arguments to pass to compiler: -interaction=nonstopmode "%pm". are you referring to this setting? Or the settings in Viewer option?

Comment: yes, replace that with `-interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "%pm"`.

Comment: ok the shell escape error is no longer popping up but i am still getting errors and the pictures are not being shown.  the first error displayed is "package pdftex.def Error: File 'Paper3_V18-pics.pdf' not found".  My .pdf filename should be 'Paper3_V18'.  I do not know to what filename 'Paper3_V18-pics.pdf' is latex referring to though.

Comment: can you look in your source folders if any .pdf files for the images have been created? or, can you search the log for any mentions of `(epstopdf)`. oh, and you did add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to the preamble as suggested in the links in my second comment?

Comment: no .pdf files for the images have been created.  i looked into .log file and i found this warning : "could not create Paper3_V18-pics.pdf".  auxiliary files not deleted.  there is also this warning "package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than 'pdftex.def' are not supported".  yes i did use \usepackage{epstopdf} in the preambple as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you have to do several things.

First prepare your code to be compilable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
% pdftex % be carefull!!: with this option: 2 errors, without: 0 errors
]{graphicx} % for \includegraphics
\usepackage{epstopdf} % to change .eps to .pdf
\epstopdfsetup{update} % conversion only if no .pdf file already created

\begin{document}
Now you should see the picture in pdf:

\includegraphics[width={\textwidth}]{example-image-a.eps}
\end{document}
```

In line 5 of the mwe I added `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to prepare the possibility to change `.eps` images to `.pdf` images. Line 6 starts `epstopdf` only, if the changed "epstopdf" file does not exist. (Please see documentation with `texdoc epstopdf`). Because you gave no MWE I can only guess what you are doing, here just a remark. In the `epstopdf` documentation is showed to call package `graphicx` with option `pdftex`.  That causes in 2 errors. Without the option the code compiles with only one warning, but wanted document!

Second you have to prepare TeXnicCenter to be able to do what you want.
Prepare a new output profile, for example `LaTeXshellescape=>PS=>PDF`.

Copy the original `LaTeX=>PS=>PDF` to the new profile, and do the following changes:

1. Add `-shell-escape` in arguments for the compiler (see red marking):

[image: Configuration (La)TeX]

Please see, that I changed `"%bm"` to `"%tm"` (see red markings).

2. Open register `Nachbearbeitung` (sorry, do not know the english name, it is the third one, see image) and check if you see:

[image: Configuration Nachbearbeitung]

With theese changes you will get the following compiled result without errors:

[image: Result of MWE]

**Alternative method with `dvipdfmx`**

You can also use an alternative method with `dvipdfmx` (see [Project KTug.org](http://project.ktug.org/dvipdfmx) or [CTAN:dvipdfmx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/dvipdfmx/)).  But then you use the way from `.dvi` to `.pdf`!

MiKTeX is not able to run several script, because Windows has no installed perl or ... interpreter.  But you can use the program `dvipdfmx.exe` (see windows directory `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`) to get the same result. Use `dvipdfmx --help` to see all possible options.  I need none of them for the example here.

With the following MWE (please see that `epstopdf` is missing)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includegraphics


\begin{document}
Now you should see the picture in pdf:

\includegraphics[width={\textwidth}]{example-image-a.eps}
\end{document}
```

and the following configuration (profile `LaTeXdvipdfmx`) for TeXnicCenter you get the wanted result.

Copy `LaTeX=>DVI=>PDF` to `LaTeXdvipdfmx`, do **not** add `-shell-escape`, change `%bm` to `%tm` (see red markings).

[image: dvtpdfmx configuration 1]

Now click on `Nachbearbeitung` and change there `dvipdfm` to `dvipdfmx` to call program `dvipdfmx.exe`.

[image]

Click ok and compile the mwe. The result is the same I showed above ...