# Package pdftex.def Error

Tags: graphics, texstudio

I am a learner to Latex. I am using Texstudio to edit the word. When I try to insert a `.eps` format figure, this error happens. `Error: Package pdftex.def Error`

The code is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics{123.eps}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot,

Hannah

Comment: You have to compile with `--shell-escape` like `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile` for `epstopdf` to work properly. Also use `graphicx` instead of `graphics`. Note the `x` at the end. Don't load `graphics` as you are loading `graphicx`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. 

PdfTeX can't work with `eps` files, thats why an extra run is required in the background that you have to allow using the `--shell-escape` switch.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383

Answer (score 13):

You should not put the extension `.eps` to the figure file. The package `epstopdf` inserts, by default,  `.eps` at the end of the graphics file name. Otherwise, you will get the error

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <example-image-b.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-05-15 17:21:24
(epstopdf)                    size: 52171 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <example-image-b-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=example-image-b-eps-convert
ed-to.pdf example-image-b.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 10.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=example-image-b-eps-converted-to.pdf example-image
-b.eps)...executed.

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <example-image-b-eps-converted-to.pdf>.


E:\Latex workshop\framed\test\only-test\doi4.tex:10: Package pdftex.def Error: 
File `example-image-b-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Second, you should use `--shell-escape` while compiling:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile
```

where `yourfile` is your main `.tex` file.

Third, don't use `graphicx` and `graphics` both. Use `graphicx` (more modern than `graphics`) and load it before `epstopdf`.

With all above, the MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to install `eps-to-pdf` converter, type in a terminal

```
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem as you described and tried a lot of methods. If you were using Mac with TexStudio, I think this could be a problem of TexStudio itself. Everything works fine with the same files for me on Windows or on Mac with other software. You may try other software to transfer the eps files to pdf files, such as Sublime or TexShop.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way for Mac users with Texstudio:
I opened a .eps file by double-clicking which launched via Preview by default, ready for save as pdf. If the .eps files are few and you are patient enough to manually export one by one, I would recommend this simple step. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. pdfTex tells you to check the log, and there I found the follwoing:

> 2016-07-24 17:45:18,822+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package graphics-def triggered by tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:18,898+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:18,898+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:18,898+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:19,013+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: lightweight database digest: 0d353e43fc36f1131535dede775291d5
>
> **2016-07-24 17:45:19,019+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Unknown archive file size.**
>
> **2016-07-24 17:45:19,019+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: package="graphics-def"**
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:19,019+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: libraries\miktex\packagemanager\internal.h
>
> 2016-07-24 17:45:19,019+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 477

The highlighted sentences gave me the feeling that there is an issue with the automated package management trying to install the missing package "graphics-def". Therefore I installed it manually via the MikTeX package manager.

Finally, LaTeX is now running fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue was caused due to mentioning full path of the pdf file. changed to the filename only. Compiles perfectly.

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{C:/Users/xx/xx/xx/figures/x.pdf}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{x.pdf}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the format from eps to pdf then worked for me. I believe there is issue with converting eps file to pdf which requires to some modification that has addressed here below:
[EPS to PDF - Remove "-eps-converted-to" from pdf filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351724/eps-to-pdf-remove-eps-converted-to-from-pdf-filename)