# EPS to PDF - Remove "-eps-converted-to" from pdf filename

Tags: epstopdf

I'm using `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to import .eps figures. Afterwards I would like to get rid off the EPS files since I have the .pdf now. I know that LaTeX does not re-convert the .eps to .pdf file in every run but I would like to remove the .eps files from my `./figure/` folder but still use the pdf file.

I have `filename.eps` in the figure folder. When I'm running  `\includegraphics{figures/filename}` LaTeX produces `filename-eps-converted-to.pdf` file.

Now I will remove all *.eps files manually to safe some space (*some of my *.eps files takes up to 400mb*) and run LaTeX again - And of course the pdf files are not found since I'm calling for `filename` not `filename-eps-converted-to`.

Now I'll either have to rename all figures or change to `\includegraphics{figures/filename-eps-converted-to}`

Is it possible to turn off that extra name?

`\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.png,.jpg}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the `epstopdf` package manual, this behaviour can be controlled by the `suffix` package option.

using in your premable

```
\epstopdfsetup{
    suffix=,
}
```

should do what you want.

The default is set to `-\SourceExt-converted-to`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had read the manual in details and I checked again. It seems we're reading different [manual](http://ctan.uib.no/support/epstopdf/epstopdf.man1.pdf). It caught my attention this was not a detailed manual.

Comment: You are looking at the manpage for the epstopdf command, not the latex package. Have a look at this one http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/epstopdf.pdf