# Figure imported from Matlab to Latex

Tags: graphics, matlab

I have a problem getting a figure from Matlab into Latex. I have saved the figure as a EPS-file in the same folder as I have saved the latex-documents. This is what I wrote in Latex:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{diffusion}
\end{figure}
```

diffusion is the name of the figure. The problem is that when I run this code in Latex, I only get much open space, but no figure. Does anyone have an ide what I should do differently?

David

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, are you using Latex or pdfLatex? My experience with eps files that is, for pdfLatex, the images must be converted to pdf first. See this question for more detail:
[Why can't pdflatex print EPS figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures)

If you are using pdfLatex, you can either output pdf files from Matlab or try adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```