# Animating multiple .eps files (>2000) using \animategraphics

Tags: eps, animations, animate

I am trying to animate a set of .eps files (>2000 images) which will give me a nice animation, but when I include it in my latex document using the MWE it is not giving me anything, but some errors. But when I use the same with .png files it works, can anyone help me with this. (The file name are as (picture-1.eps,...,picture2000.eps) and these figures are obtained from matlab for an experiment)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[H]

\animategraphics[loop,autoplay,width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{12}{picture-}{1}{2000}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work with 2 eps files? Are you using LaTeX or pdfLaTeX? What are the exact error messages you receive?

Comment: Nope it is not working with 2 eps files either, and I am using PdfLaTex and the errors I am getting are: 1. Package animate Error: Neither of the files (But the files are present in the folder I am working) 2. running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). 3. Data encoding is 'utf8'., where 2,3 are warnings

Comment: Then see here for eps in pdflatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/32374

Comment: Also, your second error looks like a warning from pgfplots that you have not set the compatibility level. If you are using pgfplots, make sure to write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` in your preamble.

Comment: But as you mentioned in the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures what should I do here to make it work, Still the error resides. Can you elaborate me in detail, on what to do here, so that I can add .eps files

Comment: The easiest is probably to convert them to PDF or PNG

Comment: Thanks and great, voila it worked and now I get the difference between latex and pdflatex..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As darthbith mentioned, convert the images in .eps to pdf/png and load it into pdflatex for displaying the graphics.