# \Includegraphics + Undefined control sequence

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I've seen this question asked multiple times but I think I have already trouble-shoot all possible problems, when using `\Includegraphics` I get the error Undefined control sequence.

I am working with MikTex in Windows. Here is my code. I already included the package and the path. I really do not know what else to do.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\graphicspath{ {C:\folder1\folder2} }

\begin{document}

\linespread{1.25}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\Large
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your example works fine. No warnings, no errors.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show the actual error message you get? Note that you talk about `\Includegraphics` in the text above the code.

Comment: use slashes not backslashes in pathes:`C:/folder1/folder2`

Comment: But in code use `\includegraphics`, what is correct

Comment: Thank you! Changed the slashes for backslashes and same error. 
In the console output is:
"The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-epstopdf.log
miktex-epstopdf: major issue: 
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `C:/Users/...' not found: using draft setting.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                                
l.28 ...raphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image} 
?"

Comment: that is a different error, not undefined command, but file not found. presumably you have the wrong file name. It is unrelated to the question title

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the error like that appears when I change the slashes for backslashes. Then I noticed that another person said it should not do a difference.
When I put it back, I get this:

"Undefined control sequence.
<argument> C:\Users 
                    \User....
l.28 ...raphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image}
                                                  
?"

I doubled check everything, to be honest I am really lost....

Comment: Maybe more light to the issue. I simply changed the .eps for a .png file and it worked like a charm.
However, I thought the preferred option in Latex was .eps
Does anybody what the problem could have been?

Comment: eps files work fine with `latex` (going through `dvi->ps->pdf`), [but not so much with `pdflatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/106162).  After correcting `\graphicspath` to use slashes (this is necessary to avoid an undefined control sequence error unrelated to your graphics problem) you get file not found, because [a suitable graphics file is not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/106162).